# Is there an AWS equivalent for volume-nfs docker image

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, nfs

Is there an AWS equivalent for volume-nfs docker image

```
gcr.io/google_containers/volume-nfs:0.8
```

My service definition file

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nfs-server
    image: gcr.io/google_containers/volume-nfs:0.8
```

Comment: What is it? I don't know AWS but very well GCP. Help me to build the bridge. Or share documentation link

Comment: its used in the context of an nfs server, I want to pull this from an AWS repo for deploying the application in AWS

Comment: And of course, you don't want to expose publicly your gcr, right? I assume that you use kubernetes correct? EKS?

Comment: Yes EKS for sure, something for dockerhub should be fine as well

Comment: Did [that](https://medium.com/hackernoon/today-i-learned-pull-docker-image-from-gcr-google-container-registry-in-any-non-gcp-kubernetes-5f8298f28969) help?

Comment: Did you manage to pull a standard nfs image from ecr or dockerhub?